# Sequence converging to a closed set

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

How can I prove that A sequence generated by a particular algorithm converges to a set? i.e irrespective of the starting point the sequence converges to any of the points in a set, or oscillates between members of the set. An example is the sequence $|x|^n + (-1)^n$ converges to the set $\{-1,1\}$ for all $-1<x<1$. Is there any general theorem for such convergence(like Cauchy condition)? Can any one suggest a good literature for the same?

Comment: Your question is nontrivial. It can be better described as "looking for the set of limit points of $\{ x_n \}_n$". In general, there are no easy anwers, since you are not specifying anything about the nature of the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to deal with convergence of sequences of functions. In your case, you have the sequence $(f_n)_{n\geq 0}$ where
$f_n(x)=|x|^n+(-1)^n$ and you seem to be interested in the function this sequence converges to and in what sense (uniform, pointwise). Hence, the literature is convergence of function sequences.

Comment: It may not be necessarily functions. say you take the sequence $x_n = .5^n + (-1)^n$.

Comment: You can also see this as a function sequence, a sequence of constant functions